# On click function doesn't run when closing tag on different line

Tags: javascript, html

I've found this interesting thing where my Onclick function doesn't work on the first click. I've come to find out that it doesn't work when the closing tag is on a new line. Is there any explanation why that's so?

```
Works
<h6 onclick="function()"> Stuff </h6>



Doesn't work
<h6 onclick="function()"> Stuff
</h6>
```

*Even in the doesn't work example, I have no whitespace at the end of the line.

**Update**:

I have added my function below. I'm trying to use plain JS. Apologies in advance for the janky JavaScript, I just started learning yesterday. This is a function that turns on and off the inline style of the proceeding element tag.

The issue I am having has continued to persist even when using both Chrome and Firefox browsers.

```
function moreInfo(id) {
    var x, sibling;
    x = document.getElementById(id);
    sibling = x.nextElementSibling;

    if (x.innerHTML === "[More]") {
        sibling.style.display = "";
        x.innerHTML = "[Less]";
    } else {
        sibling.style.display = "none";
        x.innerHTML = "[More]";
    }
}
```

The HTML in the case it doesn't work:

```
<h6 class="accordion ten" id="tip10" onclick="moreInfo('tip10')">[More]
</h6>
<p style="display: none; "> Applying to medical school... </p>
```

Comment: Why would you want to put the closing tag on a new line ?

Comment: What browser did you test this in? They both work as expected.

Comment: There has to be more to it, it's not a regular behaviour. Try to create a reproducible example here and we might be able to help.

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/83pxrzkb/

Comment: Are there any errors in the JS console?

Comment: They both work. I think you need to provide more context, first as someone above mentioned... what browser did you test this in? what's the surrounding code look like? any console errors? etc.

Comment: I have just uploaded an edit to the question. The reason I'm asking this is because of extension prettier. Sometimes it will move the closing tag to a new line.

Comment: `"[More]" !== "[More]\n"`